# ".../node_modules/rxjs/Rx" has no exported member 'throwError'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Angular documentation speaks about a "[throwError](https://angular.io/guide/http)" class whose import statement looking like the following

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

But my compiler is not able to find the class and is complaining with the following error message

> ERROR in src/app/shared/services/myservice.service.ts(3,10): error
>   TS2305: Module '"D:/workspace/dev/MyProject/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'throwError'.

Following are my environment details

> ```
> Angular CLI: 1.6.8
> Node: 8.11.1
> OS: win32 x64
> Angular: 5.2.8
> ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
> ... http, language-service, platform-browser
> ... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
>
> @angular/cdk: 5.2.4
> @angular/cli: 1.6.8
> @angular/material: 5.2.4
> @angular/service-worker: 1.0.0-beta.16
> @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
> @angular-devkit/core: 0.4.5
> @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
> @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
> @ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
> @schematics/angular: 0.1.17
> typescript: 2.4.2
> webpack: 3.10.0
> ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Here is documentation for your angular version https://v5.angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details As you can see you need to use `ErrorObservable` from `rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable`

Comment: Which is the RxJS version are you using?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you looking for the `_throw` observable?

```
import {_throw} from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
```

### update

You were looking at Angular 6 docs which includes `rxjs` version 6 that contains `throwError` function. For Angular 5 (includes `rxjs` 5) use `_throw`

Answer (score 0):

There is RxJS documentation. Link -> https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Because throw is a key word you could use `_throw` after `import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw'`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use leading `_` in `_throw`, You can do as follows:

```
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
...
const e = ErrorObservable.create(new Error('My bad'));
const e2 = new ErrorObservable(new Error('My bad too'));
```

Comment: You are importing `throw`, but using the `ErrorObservable`. The example you are giving is an alternative in case you don't like the leading `_`

Comment: @CornelC, Yeah, its an alternative. I will correct the answer. Thank you

Comment: @CornelC, and also you can edit the answers if you think they need editing. Thanks again.